# What do I do with my SSL certificates after buying them?

Tags: apache-http-server, security, ssl, xampp

OK, I have an [Apache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) server running on [XAMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP), and I have generated my [CSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_signing_request) and some fake certificates. I went to [Thawte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thawte)'s website and got an SSL trial and they emailed me back with all these other certificate code, but what do I do with them (The email is below)?

> This certificate is valid for 21 days, and will give you an 
>   opportunity to experience the installation process as well as 
>   determine your required server configuration. 
>   
>   ---------------------------------------------------------------- 
>   
>   Your Thawte trial SSL certificate: 
>   (Certificate data) 
>   
>   
>   ---------------------------------------------------------------- 
>   
>   Important installation instructions 
>   
>   For the trial SSL certificate to provide the same user 
>   experience as a trusted certificate, the Thawte Trial Secure 
>   Server Intermediate CA and the Thawte Test CA Root certificate 
>   must also be installed: 
>   
>   
>   Thawte Trial Secure Server Intermediate CA: 
>   (Certificate data) 
>   
>   
>   Thawte Test CA Root certificate: 
>   (Certificate data) 
>   
>   
>   ---------------------------------------------------------------- 
>   
>   Installing your certificate 
>   
>   Installation instructions for a range of web server solutions 
>   are available on our support site here: 
>   https://search.thawte.com/support/ssl-digital-certificates/index?page=content&id=SO7137 
>   
>   Remember, install your trial certificate on test or development 
>   servers only. The trial SSL certificate is intended for testing 
>   purposes only. 
>   
>   ---------------------------------------------------------------- 
>   
>   Your Thawte advisor will be in touch during the next 
>   few days but if you need any immediate assistance please 
>   feel free to contact us by calling, sending an e-mail or 
>   making use of our live chat facility below. 
>   
>   Thank you for your interest in thawte! 
>   
>   The Thawte Team

Comment: Try following the instructions in the link at the bottom of the email.

Comment: @NickW - Looks like the Thawte documentation page doesn't have instructions for their trial certificate on the table of instructions. https://search.thawte.com/support/ssl-digital-certificates/index?page=content&id=SO1498

Comment: Probably should not publicly post your certificates.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Copy-n-paste your Public Key into a text file on your computer. Something like `C:\XAMPP\SSL\Public.pem`. Notepad works fine.
2. Download the Certificate Bundle/Chain from Thwarte: https://search.thawte.com/library/VERISIGN/ALL_OTHER/thawte%20ca/SSL123_CA_Bundle.pem
   Save it in the same directory as #1
3. Move your Private Key, the one you used to generate the CSR, to the same folder as #1. Call it `Private.pem` or something logical.

Now you've got your keys... Next configure Apache.

In your httpd.conf file:

```
SSLCertificateFile C:\XAMPP\SSL\Public.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile C:\XAMPP\SSL\Private.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile C:\XAMPP\SSL\SSL123_CA_Bundle.pem
```

File names and locations subject to change depending on what you did in the above steps.